# Sql Get the last 6

Tags: sql

I need a sql query that use the Records ID to get the last 6 times of the trips also the number of time.

So the records in the table are like the following,

```
RecordID  Nooftime  Day&Time
1001        1         12/11/2009 14:11
1001        2         13/11/2009 12:11
1001        3         14/11/2009 11:11
1001        4         16/11/2009 14:11
1001        5         17/11/2009 14:11
1001        6         20/11/2009 13:11
1001        7         25/11/2009 09:11
```

I Need a query that show only the last 6 vist's and in one line.

Comment: What kind of sql database are you using? The syntax is different for different providers.

Comment: One hopes the Day&Time column is "datetime" or similar. Not varchar...?

Comment: i'm using 2000 and the column is datatime field

Answer (score 6):

If you're dealing with SQL Server try

```
Select Top 6 RecordID, NoOfTime, Day&Time from (table) order by Day&Time DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

### Oracle

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM (SELECT t.* 
          FROM TABLE t 
      ORDER BY day&time DESC) x
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 6
```

### SQL Server

```
  SELECT TOP 6 t.* 
    FROM TABLE t 
ORDER BY day&time DESC
```

### MySQL/Postgres

```
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM TABLE t 
ORDER BY day&time DESC
   LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Mind that you really shouldn't be naming a column using the ampersand character - it will likely have to be escaped to work.

Comment: Your Oracle sample doesn't work because the ORDER BY doesn't get applied until AFTER the WHERE clause is evaluated for each row.  The idiom for Oracle is "select * from (select t.* from t order by x) where rownum <= n"

Comment: @kurosch: Thx, don't have Oracle onhand to test, corrected.  I should have gone with my instinct & provided both with caveat explaining why.

Comment: why the 'FROM TABLE' and 't.*' syntax. Isn't SQL verbose enough without using the most verbose syntax ? Also I do not used Oracle but I wonder there is no shorthand for getting only some results from result set... I guess I will google for this one.

Comment: @kriss: `t` is a table alias - it's required when accessing tables with identically named columns in order for the db to know which column to use.  It also means less typing, and is a good habit to have.  Regarding "some of the results from the resultset" - there's ANSI SQL, but that doesn't mean every DB implements those.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RecordID, NoofTime, Day&Time FROM table ORDER BY Day&Time DESC LIMIT 6;
```

depending on your SQL engine you will probably have to put some quotes around Day&Time.

The above syntax works with Mysql and PostgreSQL, for varous syntax used for this kins of request you can have a look there [select-limit](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#select-limit)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT TOP(6) *
FROM [Trips]
ORDER BY [Day&Time] DESC
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "in one line," but this will fetch the 6 most recent records.

Comment: cmsjr beat me to it.  This is essentially the same as his solution, and yes, the query may be slightly different if you're using a database other than SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

For the same line portion, you can use a cursor if you are using SQL server 2008 (might work with 2005 I am not sure).